# Find the area enclosed by $2|x| + 3|y| < 6$

Tags: calculus, geometry

Find the area enclosed by $ 2|x| + 3|y| \lt 6 $. Is there any way to do this without drawing the graph?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I have made the required changes.

Comment: Why do you want to do it without graph? It will make things unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Separate the inequality in four cases : $(x \geq 0, y \geq 0),(x < 0, y \geq 0),(x \geq 0, y < 0),(x < 0, y < 0)$.

Comment: The *first* thing that you should do is draw a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. We have a rhombus with diagonals $4$ and $6$ and the area is $\frac{4\cdot6}{2}=12$.

We can understand that it's rhombus by the following reasoning.

Our figure is symmetric in-relation to axis $x$ and it's symmetric in-relation to axis $y$.

For the vertexes we need $x=0$ or $y=0$ and the rest is easy.

Comment: How do you know that it is a rhombus? Please elaborate your answer. Also, if i am given any arbitrary inequality similar to the one in my question, then how will I be able to identify the shape and how will I be able to get its area if the shape is a complicated one? Is there any way by which we can integrate the expression.

Comment: @Akshat Joshi I fixed my post. See now.